# Why is Ant design less styles not applied in nextjs app with Webpack5?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, webpack-5

I am building a sample Nextjs app with webpack5 and for UI I am using Antd framework. I do not see the styles applied at all. When I go in the dev tools I do see ant classes applied to buttons but they are not styled. Here are my files:

globals.less:

```
@import 'antd/dist/antd.less';
```

_app.js:

```
import "../styles/globals.less";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

next.config.js: (for providing loaders and to use webpack5)

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
        },
        {
          loader: "less-loader", // compiles Less to CSS
          options: {
            lessOptions: {
              // If you are using less-loader@5 please spread the lessOptions to options directly
              modifyVars: {
                "primary-color": "#1DA57A",
                "link-color": "#1DA57A",
                "border-radius-base": "2px",
              },
              javascriptEnabled: true,
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

index.js:

```
import { Button } from 'antd'
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main >
        <h1 >
          Welcome to Nextjs
        </h1>
        <div>
          <Button type="primary">Primary Test</Button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-less": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^4.15.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

When I look at the page through dev tools I don't even see the script tag.

Edit:
for anyone saying use ~ in the path to less file please note that starting ver 8.0.0 it's been depracated. Here is the link to changelog:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: just check the official example to see if you get anything wrong with your configs Next.js github page has a lot of examples,
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design-less. 
I suspect your problem is from the less file path being wrong. You probably can check the devTools to see if the `less` file is being correctly loaded

Comment: when i use the example you mentioned I get this error: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'

Comment: To clarify, is the issue specific to webpack 5? Does it work if you disable the `webpack5` flag in the config?

Comment: it seems that way and reason why I am saying this is I had it working with Webpack4 but with wp4 I had to downgrade Less-Loader to 7.3.0 otherwise I was getting the getOptions is not a function error. And the getOptions error is due to the lessOptions object in next.config.js file.

Comment: were you able to get this going ?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to [`less-loader` v8.0.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800-2021-02-01), you'll need to add a `~` to your `antd.less` import to tell the webpack loader to resolve the import from the `node_modules` directory.

```css
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
```

Comment: that's not correct. If you read changelog for less-loader you don't need ~ anymore starting 8.0.0. here is the changelog: "using ~ is deprecated and can be removed from your code (we recommend it), but we still support it for historical reasons." and link: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Fair enough. It might not be the solution for your specific case but could still be useful for anyone not using v8.0.0, so I'll leave the answer there.